# Android: How to get Drawable xml name

Tags: java, android, path, imageview, android-vectordrawable

I want to get the name of the drawable xml and want to store that name in a string. For example , for a xml, I might use  .xml file named a.xml or b.xml I just want to know which xml in drawable is used for the ImageView.. Is there any way to get the name of the drawable/(??.xml)

Thanks.